# Почему одинаковые ответы на разную информацию в keras?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(xTrain.shape[1], xTrain.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

А на пустой и отличные вектор ответ одинаковый или почти одинаковый

```
[[ 0.72918308  0.27081689]]
[[ 0.72915727  0.27084273]]
[[ 0.45769805  0.54230195]]
[[ 0.45769805  0.54230195]]
```